# Where can I find out about Stack Overflow history?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange-history

I'd like to know how Stack Overflow and other sites started - which was first, who initiated it (OK, that's on the link below) and why, how the different sites evolved, how the rules evolved, etc.

Where can I find such information?

Of course, I know I can look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#History) for a brief overview but I'm wondering if there is info on this site, particularly more detailed..

Comment: I actually started working on improving the Wikipedia page of StackOverflow if anyone has any info to contribute..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best place to start is the old episodes of [the podcast](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html).  They trace the early history in some detail.  The old articles on [the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/) will also have a lot of the information you're after.  A lot of the history of how the rules evolved is right here on meta.

Comment: Those are two very cool links - thanks! I especially like that you can easily go right back to the early history (e.g. the logo competition).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not old enough to have used it myself, but you might want to check out UserVoice, which was in many ways the predecessor of Meta.

Comment: I didn't know about UserVoice - thanks.

Comment: I always forget about UserVoice.  :)

Comment: @Bill I didn't realize UserVoice was still up.

Comment: @devinb: Me either.  I didn't use it much to begin with, but I haven't visited since I got the email inviting me to meta.

Comment: I *try* to forget about UserVoice, but the trauma is still to raw...

Answer (score 2):

Here's the original blog post on Coding Horror that resulted in the naming of StackOverflow:  http://blog.codinghorror.com/help-name-our-website/

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread (historical?), but I was looking for the same question. I also suggest visiting The [Internet Archive's Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/web.php). It's neat to see old versions of the site.