# When was Stack Overflow first released?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I always had a question in my mind; ever since I have started coding, Stack Overflow has turned out to be a good solution finder for me.

- When was Stack Overflow first released?
- Who was the first one to register to the site?

I have seen that the site was under maintenance a few days ago, so I thought it's time for me to end the surprise I have been keeping in my mind and shoot.

Comment: some info here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58210/where-can-i-find-out-about-stack-overflow-history

Answer (score 5):

The public beta of Stack Overflow started on the 31st of July, 2008.

The site came out of beta on the 15th of September 2008.

The user with Id 1 is [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood), one of the founders.