# Who is the chief executive officer of Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, help-center, community

I am a new contributor to Stack Exchange, and it has so many websites... the tour page explains it all. I've been through *some* sites, such as Stack Overflow, and it is well designed! It's almost like another entire website I know... but I was wondering, who owns the community that they have done this whole hard work?

Also, please let me know if the CEO is on the Help Center, because I have looked there.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/ceo/info

Comment: If you want to learn more about the people who create this website you can start with the [history section on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#History) and this old question: [Where can I find out about Stack Overflow history?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58210/where-can-i-find-out-about-stack-overflow-history)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since [apparently nobody ever linked to that page before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fcompany%2Fleadership), let me share you a link to where this is mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/company/leadership

[image]

You can read Prashanth Chandrasekar's bio [here](https://stackoverflow.com/company/leadership/prashanth-chandrasekar), and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/579126/prashanth-chandrasekar) is his user account.

> who owns the community that they have done this whole hard work

That's ... actually not what a [CEO does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_executive_officer#Responsibilities).

Comment: Why do you know what a Chief Executive Officer is, but not what they do?

Answer (score 2):

From https://stackoverflow.com/company/leadership:  Prashanth Chandrasekar is the current Stack Overflow CEO.